# Ant Build Failed

Tags: android, ant

I am trying to build an Android Project using **Apache Ant** through **Command Line** but it is giving me **Build Failed** with the following error statements:
Java.io.IOException: Cannot run Program. "..\android_sdk\platform-tools\aapt.exe"

**D:\MediaSync\build.xml:429: Execute failed: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "..\android_sdk\platform-tools\aapt.exe"**

I am new to this thing so i am not getting any idea how to get over this error. Searched alot about it but still scratching my head..
Anybody any idea about it then please tell me.

**EDIT:**  Here are parts of my Buil.xml file

```
<!-- General SDK location -->
<property name="sdk-folder" value="D:/sdk" />  

<!-- Preset tools location -->
<property name="android-platform-tools" value="${sdk-folder}/platform-tools"/> 

 <!-- Tools -->
<condition property="aapt" value="${android-platform-tools}/aapt.exe" else="${android-platform-tools}/aapt" >
    <os family="windows"/>
</condition>  


<!-- Generate the R.java file for this project's resources. -->
<target name="resource-src" depends="init, localization, replace-template-values">
    <echo>Generating R.java / Manifest.java from the resources...</echo>
    <exec executable="${aapt}" failonerror="true">
        <arg value="package" />
        <arg value="-m" />
        <arg value="-J" />
        <arg value="${outdir-r}" />
        <arg value="-M" />
        <arg value="${outdir.manifest}/AndroidManifest.xml" />
        <arg value="-S" />
        <arg value="${resource-dir}" />
        <arg value="-I" />
        <arg value="${android-jar}" />
    </exec>

</target>
```

Comment: Have you found the solution to your problem..?

Comment: @AmritpalSingh.. I actually dont remember what i did that time. You may try below answers.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure aapt.exe is installed at the correct path relative to your build.xml file (../android_sdk/platform-tools). That path is likely relative to your project, but not the build.xml.

Comment: appt.exe is rightly in the platform-tools folder. I my Android SDK is placed in C drive. So the full path for aapt.exe is as follows:
C:\android-sdk-windows\sdk\platform-tools\aapt.exe\. !!!

bt still its not building the project

Comment: To avoid confusion you could also use an absolute path.

Comment: @javadeveloper.. how can i use that?
Can you plz show me example

Answer (score 3):

I encountered the same problem on a 64-bit fedora platform and finally worked it out following this: http://blog.mx17.net/2012/10/25/android-on-ubuntu-ioexception-on-aapt/

It had failed because of trying to run a 32-bit program on an 64-bit architecture. 
Maybe this would help.

Comment: @yangxu... Thank you for your response... I have compiled the code.. my problem was that the project installation guide was not up to date.

Answer (score 1):

Your error message says:

> D:\MediaSync\build.xml:429: Execute failed: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "..\android_sdk\platform-tools\aapt.exe"

while your aapt.exe is located in:

> C:\android-sdk-windows\sdk\platform-tools\aapt.exe\

Obviously the build.xml tries to search `D:\` for `android_sdk\platform-tools\aapt.exe`, which is the wrong path.

There should be a property for you to specify the path of aapt.exe, or it reads from system's PATH varibles.

To get a solution, post the lines around line 429 in build.xml. In line 429, there should be a `<exec>` task, be sure to include the whole content of that task (copy from `<exec ...>` to `</exec>`).

Comment: @coolcfan.. I had already set the correct path for "Platform-tools" folder and "Tools" in system variables and have mentioned correct path in Build.properties for SDK...
And if i set absolute path for android SDK in Build.xml file then again build fails..

Comment: @Noman So, what's the value of `${aapt}`? It's a property, check your build.xml and properties files for "aapt". Also, you can use `<echo>` to output the value of `${aapt}` -- just add an echo line before `<exec>`.

Comment: @coolcfan... its values is in front of you. And its correct. No problem with that thing..

Comment: @coolcfan... Thank you for your response... I have compiled the code.. my problem was that the project installation guide was not up to date.

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug in the intellij android studio and perhaps other IDEs that points to platform-tools for some executables/libs that now live in build-toos.  A workaround for now is to make sim-links fof the necessary files.

So on linux/mac

```
platform-tools$ ln -s ../build-tools/android-version-blah/bin/appt appt
```

## and

```
platform-tools$ ln -s ../build-tools/android-version-blah/lib lib
```

for Windows, install LinkExtensions and replace ln with `mklink` and read the help from typing `mklink` with no args. In Windows, the file would be appt.exe

Answer (score 0):

A quick fix you can do is copy the aapt.exe and lib folder from the build-tools to the platform-tools folder.